# Vue.js 3 - State Management - How to call a method from an ancestor

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue 3 app. I'm using the Composition API as I've read it simplifies state management. As a result, I'm trying to to *avoid* using VueX. Perhaps, I've run into a scenario that warrants it. I currently have the following component structure in my app...

**App**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
| +-----------------+    +--------------------+     |
| | Component 1     |    | Component 2        |     |
| | +-------------+ |    |                    |     |
| | | Component A | |    +--------------------+     |
| | +-------------+ |                               |
| |                 |                               |
| | +-------------+ |                               |
| | | Component B | |                               |
| | +-------------+ |                               |
| +-----------------+                               |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

This whole app revolves around setting properties of a single `item`. The `item` can be initially set via `Component 1` or in `Component B`. You can set properties on the `item` via `Component A`. When a user clicks a button in `Component 2`, I want to force a method in `Component A` to run. However, I haven't figured out how to do that.

Currently, in `Component 2` I use `this.$emit('forceRefresh')` when the button is clicked. However, `$emit` only let's me go up the stack. I'm not sure how to go down the stack once I've reached the top. I tried using a computed property in `Component A` however, that didn't work. I feel stuck, like I'm doing this wrong. Still, I know there's a way, I'm just unsure of what that way is.

Comment: if you want to use event bus please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus/64019074#64019074

Comment: maybe try using provide-inject https://blog.logrocket.com/provide-inject-vue-js-3-composition-api/  <-- here is a paragraph on how to make it reactive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Vue.js event bus.
Essentially, an event bus is a Vue.js instance that can emit events in one component, and then listen and react to the emitted event in another component directly — without the help of a parent component.

Here is reference link that can help you .
[1](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/)https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/

```
export const bus = new Vue(); //in main.js

import { bus } from '../main'; //in component "B" and in click call the method and insted of emitting do
bus.$emit('changeIt', 'forceRefresh');

in component "A" in Mounted() add also import{ bus } 
bus.$on('changeIt', (data) => {
  //do the component refresh
})
```

Comment: While the event bus approach is interesting, the problem is, the `$on` method was removed from Vue 3. I know it was in Vue 2. However, I do not see it in the Vue 3 docs.

Comment: Use the following library mitt - https://github.com/developit/mitt

Just make a small change 

`import mitt from 'mitt';`
`const bus = mitt(); `
`bus.emit` and `bus.on`