# Declare prototype property in vuejs with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am declaring $bus in vue prototype to access globaly but getting this error

```
Property `prototype` does not exist on type vue.
```

Can some help me how to declare with typescript. Vue version is 3.

Comment: to create an event bus please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019074/8172857

Answer (score 0):

You would no longer inject it into the Vue prototype. If you want to make it globally accessible in a way that is similar to the prototype method you could use the global properties from the application instance.

```js
const appInstance = createApp(MyVueApp);
appInstance.config.globalProperties.$bus = myBus;
appInstance.mount('#appId');
```

if you want to access it from a component, for Option-API components, you can access with `this.$bus`. For Composition API, you need to get the instance with `getCurrentInstance` Vue method, so: `getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$bus`

I don't believe there's anything specific to typescript in terms of adding the object to the instance, but you might need to type the `$bus` when you're getting it from the `globalProerties` object.