# Vue 3 migration how to do extend of a component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, extend

I have a component

```
const DialogMain = Vue.extend(DialogComponent);

export const alertDialog = (text: string) => {
  const dialog = new DialogMain({
    propsData: {
      type: 'alert'    
    },
  });

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // resolve reject handle here
    }
  });
```

So when I migrate the app to Vue3 I get `'extend' does not exist on type 'typeof import('....')` error. I know since the global Vue is no longer a new-able constructor, `Vue.extend` no longer makes sense in terms of constructor extension. But I am not sure how to write it with defineComponent. Is it should be like

```
const dialogMain = defineComponent({extends: DialogComponent})
```

Will it be same as `Vue.extend`?

Comment: A related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732406/how-to-programmatically-create-a-component-instance-in-vue-3/69734085#69734085 . This may be a bad practice to detach Vue instance from the app without a reason. For screen components there are teleports. You can mount it once within root component and control its visibility across the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use the component options as is?

```
const DialogMain = defineComponent(DialogComponent)
```