# How to setup a Global Event bus in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am creating a Vue 3 app and trying to implement a Global event bus for two components to communicate on. In past w/Vue 2
I would do the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
export const bus = new Vue();
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Now w/Vue 3 I understand new Vue is out and createApp() is in. I thus setup bus as:

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

export const bus = createApp();

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

And App.vue is:

```
<template>
  <!-- ============== Modal Component ============= -->
  <FormModal v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal">
    <template v-slot:header> Add Equipment Item to Scrap List </template>
  </FormModal>

 
    <!-- More template stuff -->

  <DisplayScrap />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import FormModal from "./components/form-modal.vue";
import DisplayScrap from "./components/display-scrap.vue";
```

Now when I go to the first component(The emitter) and try to import the Global bus :

```
// form.modal.vue
import { reactive, defineEmits, ref, toRaw } from "vue";
import addRow from "../helperFunctions/addRow.js";
import { bus } from "../main.js";
```

I now get error in console of:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'App' before initialization
 http://localhost:3000/src/main.js?t=1640126294730:7
main.js:7:1*

Any advise on what is the proper way in Vue 3 to setup the global bus  is most appreciated. Am I missing some circular reference that is causing the error? I don't see any example in the Docs for this type of situation...

Comment: Yes. I was trying to adapt a Vue 2 solution. But it looks like the whole $emit() and $on() macros have been eliminated in Vue 3. I was trying to avoid another dependency like mitt to my project. I don't know if that is possible now.

Comment: `$emit` actually is kept. they deleted `$on`, `$off` and `$once`

Comment: This question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First the error:

  did you try to  `export const bus = createApp();` in a different file to avoid circular ref ?
- Regarding global bus in vue3:

  it is recommended to use a global state like what `vuex` provide you or any external package as best practice to communicate between components.

  and even if you managed to import the created `bus` you still don't have the listener `$on` to receive the emitted data. as they deleted it in `vue3`

Comment: Yes. I see in the Docs they deleted $on. Vuex seems like over kill. I just have one instance where two components need to exchange state. I was hoping to avoid another dependency. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Alan if this is the case. maybe implement your simple event emitter is what you are looking for ? look into some implementation here https://gist.github.com/mudge/5830382

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue, and I found the [vue3-eventbus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-eventbus) to be the exact simple solution. It provides support for Vue2, Vue3, compositions API and also Typescript support. I rate this plugin highly.