# How can i sync scroll event of two vue components in non parent-child relation?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vuejs3

How can i sync scroll event of two vue component i a non-parent-child relation

Scrolling here ...

**BaseLayout.vue**

```
<script setup>
...
function logScrolling(event) {
  console.log("Scrolling to " + event.detail.currentY);
  // rightIonContent.value.$el.scrollToPoint(X, Y, 500); // this is not working
}
...
</script>

<template>
...
    <ion-content :scroll-events="true" @ionScroll="logScrolling($event)" >
      <slot />
    </ion-content>
...
</template>
```

should be synced with:

**AppMenuRight.vue**

```
<script setup>
function ScrollingToPoint(X, Y) {
  rightIonContent.value.$el.scrollToPoint(X, Y, 500);
}
</script>

<template>
...
    <ion-content :scroll-events="true" ref="rightIonContent">
    ...
    </ion-content>
...
</template>
```

Comment: I have used the option with useEmitter.js described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus/64019074#64019074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the option with useEmitter.js described here: [Vue.js 3 Event Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus/64019074#64019074)

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default function useEmitter() {
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance(); 
    const emitter = internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.emitter;

    return emitter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BaseLayout should set scroll value in vuex store. Than Other component can watch that property and set element scroll value accordingly in the watcher

Comment: Thanks, but i don't use Vuex Store