# How to use $root.$on to catch an emit from another component in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, emit

In Vue2 i was using **$root.$emit** and **$root.$on** among components,
but in Vue3, i cant find the substitute for **$root.$on** .

```
    //ComponentA.vue
    this.$root.$emit('code-fulfill', response.unique_key);

    //ComponentZ.vue
    this.$root.$on('code-fulfill', (code) => {
       this.code = code;
    });
```

***how to do the same in Vue3 ?***

i know how i can do do the emit,

```
//ComponentA.vue
<script setup lang="ts">

const emit = defineEmits(['update-number'])
//then 
emit('update-number', 4455)

//ComponentZ.vue
**???????**
```

but the **$root.$on** i have no idea how to do it, because the root property has no more the property **$on**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63471824/8172857