# Vue 3: How to forward all emitted events to a parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following structure of Vue components:

```html
<TopParent> <!-- listen for EventProducer's events here -->
  <Child_1>
    <Child_2>
      <Child_3>
        ... 
        <Child_N>
          <EventProducer /> <!-- emit events here --> 
        </Child_N>

      </Child_3>
    </Child_2>
  </Child_1>
</TopParent>
```

**Question**

I want to `emit` an event in `<EventProducer>` component and listen to the event in `<TopParent>` component?

How can I tell all the `<Child_1>...<Child_N>` components to just forward event to the parent?

P.S. I don't want to specify the exact names of the event, just to forward all of the events.

---

**A stupid solution**

In a very primitive way I could do it like this. But it very verbose, especially when there are more than 1 event:

```html
<TopParent @foo="doTheJob()">
  <Child_1  @foo="emit('foo')">
    <Child_2  @foo="emit('foo')">
      <Child_3  @foo="emit('foo')">
        ... 
        <Child_N @foo="emit('foo')">
          <EventProducer @click="emit('foo')"/> 
        </Child_N>

      </Child_3>
    </Child_2>
  </Child_1>
</TopParent>
```

I believe there is a better way than this.

Comment: Use *Provide / Inject* 
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Comment: @BinRohan Correct me, but provide/inject pass values from parent to child, not the way around (which is the case). Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You can inject an event bus or an object that needs to be changed, depending on what's foo is for

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824) has some good ideas for accomplishing what you want

Comment: Like @yoduh said - use an event bus. Every component can emit events to the bus and every component can subscribe to the bus. If the component does not emit events to the bus but to itself - you will have to explicitly listen for the events that are interesting to you in the immediate parent of the component in question, and then re-emit those events to the event bus so that every other interested component can receive these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) feature.

The idea is to provide a kind of "callback function" from `TopParent` to `EventProducer`.

Inside the `TopParent` component:

```js
import { provide } from 'vue';

...
function activateOnEvent() {
  //...
}

provide('parentFn', activateOnEvent); //key, value
```

Inside the `EventProducer` component:

```
import { inject } from 'vue';
...
const parentFn = inject('parentFn');
...
<button @click="parentFn()">Click</button>
```

So, on your event you can directly call a function from the `TopParent` component.

Answer (score 2):

**there are a couple of ways to pass your data to child/parent component. Before implementation pay attention to what you need exactly**

1. [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) *(can be global)*
2. store [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/); [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) *(can be global)*
3. [emit/props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) *(just parent/child)*
4. useComposition *(can be global)*

```
// composition file 
import { ref } from 'vue'

const someString = ref<string>('')

export const useComposition = () => {
  return {
    someString,
  }
}
```

```
// usage 
import { useComposition } from 'path/to/file'
const { someString } = useComposition()
```