# this.emitter is undefined (using mitt)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create an event bus setup in Vuejs 3 using mitt. I am following this Stackoverflow solution [Vue.js3 Event Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus) but it's not working. Here is my setup:

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import mitt from 'mitt'

const emitter = mitt()
createApp(App).config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```
// fire emitter event
emitFunction(){
  this.emitter.emit('hideMenu', true)
},
```

```
// listening for emitter
mounted(){
  this.emitter.on('hideMenu', (state) => {console.log(state)})
}
```

However, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.emitter is undefined`

PS. It is not the same problem as this other question where the problem is how to access 'this' inside a callback: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are creating the app twice and therefore, invalidating the initial config you set. In fact it is the second instance of `createApp` that you mounted, which doesn't contain the config you set.

Try putting the created app into a variable and then configure it.

See below.

```
const emitter = mitt()
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
app.use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create file like `EventBus.ts`:

```
import mitt from "mitt";

export default mitt()
```

And `import EventBus` where needed.

Comment: This is a very elegant and simple solution to the duplicate instance problem.